# Amazon S3 managing files in versioned bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 as images server.

I use php API to put and delete objects to bucket with versions.
Now i want to rename folder at S3, i understand that physically i will have to copy paste those files but with another path in folder-name place, and after copy i want all pics from old folder to be erased(in order not to occupy memory). However, my bucket has versions, so that means my erase iteration will just set delete markers and do nothing physically.

Is there a way to get all versions of i-th file as a list, and iterate over them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you wil have to write some code.

There is an API that let you retrieve all versions of an object in a bucket. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html

Based on this (and higher level SDK or AWS CLI equivalent) developing the behaviour you describe is relatively easy.